# Sharing data between services and activities

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter, that shows orders from an ArrayList. These orders are supposed to be synced with my server. There I have an API, which I am requesting for new orders, and if there are any, I get an XML of the order back. What is the best approach to dynamically update the listView? I do not want to use SQLite to store the orders, because only last ten are supposed to be displayed. With a ContentProvider I am not able to store my custom Order object. And if I wrap the ArrayList into a singleton class and use it in the service as well as in the Activity class for the ArrayAdapter, the ListView is not dynamically updated (probably, because the arrayAdapter makes a copy of the arraylist?). Thank you very much.

Filip

Answer (score 1):

use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Answer (score 1):

i'm no sure what you mean regarding the ArrayAdapter not being updated, but i can give you a solution we used in my company.

I have a DataMaanger which is a bridge between the Activities and the Networking or SQLite.
The dataMaanger keeps it's data in memory so it's not in DB or on disk. the disadvantage of it is if your app gets killed for lack of memory and reconstructs itself, the dataManager will be empty, which leaves you with two options, either on every Activitie's death or you main task's activities death you serialize your DataManager's data, or if you are not dependant on any previous data, just make  arequest again and update the data manager.
I use broadcasts to notify my activities.

To get an access to the DataManager i don't use a sigletone. i use the Application object, you can extend it and in the Manifest.xml give it's name in the  tag, then it will be used instead of the regualr Application object.

You can access it later by using getApplication() method in Activity class.